# Strange radio button behaviour in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I came across an strange case GWT related with RadioButtons. I built component which consist from multiple radio inside lets call it X. One radio inside X is selected by default. But if I use this component N times in one view then only in the last X default selection works. As an example:

For instace
let's build aggregator ui

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
   <cc:RadioButtonComponent ui:field="one"/>
   <br/>
   <cc:RadioButtonComponent ui:field="two"/>

</g:HTMLPanel>
```

class

```
public class AggregatorComponent extends Composite {

    private static AggregatorComponentUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(AggregatorComponentUiBinder.class);

    interface AggregatorComponentUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, AggregatorComponent> {
    }

    @UiField
    RadioButtonComponent one;
    @UiField
    RadioButtonComponent two;
    
    public AggregatorComponent() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

and example RadioButtonComponent ui

```
<g:HTMLPanel>

   <g:RadioButton ui:field="radioOne" name="radioGroup"/>
   <g:RadioButton ui:field="radioTwo" name="radioGroup"/>
   <br/>
   <g:CheckBox ui:field="checkBox1"/>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

and class

```
public class RadioButtonComponent extends Composite {

    private static RadioButtonComponentUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(RadioButtonComponentUiBinder.class);

    interface RadioButtonComponentUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, RadioButtonComponent> {
    }

    @UiField
    RadioButton radioOne;

    @UiField
    RadioButton radioTwo;
    
    @UiField
    CheckBox checkBox1;
    
    public RadioButtonComponent() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    radioOne.setValue(true);
    checkBox1.setValue(true);
    }

}
```

checkbox works well in this case.

Result looks like this:

[image]

and unseleced radio has indeed checked
`<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="on" id="gwt-uid-6" tabindex="0" checked="">` but this one bellow has the same checked value only id is different.

**QUESTION**

Is this a bug ?
How to overcome this obstacle ?

Tested on GWT 2.8 Java 8
Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87, FireFox 56 and IE 11

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons are grouped based on their name, so you need to give different names to each group (either pass one to `RadioButtonComponent` or generate a unique one inside it)